# Solve system of linear differential equations by elimination

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ (D-4)x + D^2y = t^2 $$
$$ (D+1)x+Dy=0 $$

I expanded. $$Dx-4x+D^2y=t^2$$
$$ Dx+x+Dy=0 $$

I need help eliminating x.

Question 2: I need help eliminating x or y.

$$ Dx+D^2y = e^{3t} $$
$$ (D+1)x + (D-1)y = 4e^{3t} $$

Comment: What does $D$ mean?  I don't understand your notation.  I'm guessing that $D \equiv \frac{d}{dx}$ or perhaps $D \equiv \frac{d}{dt}$???  If it's the latter...it would be much easier to write as $-4x + \dot{x} + \ddot{y}   = t^2$ and $x + \dot{x} + \dot{y} = 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply first equation by (D+1). Multiply second equation by (D-4). Then subtract to get
$$ D^3y+4Dy = Dt^2 + t^2 $$
$$ y(D^3+4D) = 2t + t^2 $$
I can solve the rest on my own.